# How to use a method from a class in main

Tags: java

I have created a method called LineOfRegression and I want to print out an example line of regression with the slope of 0.18784 and a intercept of -7.964. How would I do this in main? (I've pasted the whole class for reference; The LineOfRegression method is at the bottom)

```
package com.company;

public class ScatterPlot {
    public Point[]points = null;

    ScatterPlot(Point p){
        points = new Point[1];
        points[0] = p;
    }
    public void addPoint(Point p){
        Point[]temp = null;
        if(points==null || points.length == 0){
            points = new Point[1];
            points[0] = p;
        }
        else{
            temp = new Point[points.length+1];
            //use a for loop to copy points into temp
            for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
                temp[i] = points[i];
            }
            //add the new Point p into the last element
            temp[points.length] = p;
            //copy over temp
            points = temp;
        }
    }
    public boolean removeIndex(int index) {
        //Points is null
        if(points == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(points.length==0){
            return false;
        }
        //Out of bounds index
        if(index >= points.length || index <0){
            return false;
        }

        //{p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5} index = 3
        //P0 - P2
        //Copy elements before remove
        Point[] newArray = new Point[points.length-1];
        for(int i = 0; i<index;i++){
            newArray[i] = points[i];
        }
        //Copy elements after remove
        for(int i = index; i<newArray.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = points[i+1];
        }
        points = newArray;
        return true;
    }
    void printReport(){
        System.out.println("Number of points " + points.length);
        System.out.println("Line of Regression is " + lineOfRegression().toStr());
    }
    public Line lineOfRegression(){
        double n = points.length;
        double sigmaX = 0;
        double sigmaY = 0;
        double sigmaXY = 0;
        double sigmaXSquared = 0;

        for(int count = 0; count<= n; count++){
            sigmaX = sigmaX + points[count].getXCoordinate();
            sigmaY = sigmaY + points[count].getYCoordinate();
            sigmaXY = sigmaXY + points[count].getXCoordinate() * points[count].getYCoordinate();
        }
        double slope = (n * sigmaXY) - (sigmaX * sigmaY) / (n + (sigmaXSquared)) - (sigmaXSquared);
        double intercept = (sigmaY - (slope * sigmaX)) / n;

        Line regressionLine = new Line(slope,intercept);
        return regressionLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? do you mean you want to create an example Lane with the values you want to use but you don't want to use the full class?

Comment: @Bruno Delor I just want to use the LineOfRegression method in the main class.

Comment: well as it is not static you will need to instantiate an instance of `ScatterPlot`

Comment: Well I ask because you write very specific numbers in your question